# Installing Basic Python Modules

Tags: python, python-3.3, distribute

I first downloaded Python 3.3 with the purpose of then adding xlrd and xlwt to use with excel. I have been unable to install `easy_install`, `distribute`, or either of the above.

This is an error message I get after downloading distribute, extracting it and running `distribute_setup.py` from IDLE:

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.49.tar.gz
Extracting in c:\users\t\appdata\local\temp\tmpecnfj9
Now working in c:\users\t\appdata\local\temp\tmpecnfj9\distribute-0.6.49
Installing Distribute
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.49\distribute_setup.py", line 556, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
SystemExit: 2
```

Overall, I am unable to install and use any modules. I assume I am missing a very basic step.

Comment: Have you tried running it outside of IDLE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows Try this.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.3, `setuptools` replaces `distribute`. Download and install `setuptools` and you should be good to go. You might also want to consider installing `pip` after installing setuptools. Follow the directions for [`setuptools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8) and [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) in [`pypi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Answer (score 0):

Install Python in a drive where you have downloaded the Python Source which is in .msi format or you can change the drive of that source file and then try to install it. Just a simple installation process, nothing typical.

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Make sure you have done the following

1. **Ensure that you have python and pip installed** and accessible from the command line. Type both of these commands to ensure that you have python and pip3 installed:
   a. `pip3`
   b. `python3`
   If you got any message telling you that you do not have them installed on your system
2. **Use the `pip3 install PACKAGE_NAME_HERE` command** in your terminal/cmd to install modules/packages
3. **If you get the pip3 command not found error**, then type the respective command
   a)If you are on a mac device, install brew: `brew install python3`. Then install pip3: `brew postinstall python3`. Then call `pip3 -V` to see if it works.
   b) If you are on a Linux device, use, `sudo apt install python3-pip` to install pip